# WSO2 Docker container text editor

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm running WSO2 APIM on the [official Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2am). What's the best way to edit text files from inside of it? Default container doesn't have nano, vi, vim or any other editor AFAIK.

When logged into container using 
`docker exec -it api-manager /bin/bash`
, I've tried:

```
apt-get install vim
```

permission denied

```
su apt-get install vim
```

asks for a password.

What's the proper way to edit configuration files in the container?

Comment: What is the point or need to edit config files in the container , if you need to modify the config files mount them externally through volume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run bash as the root user, using `docker exec -it -u root api-manager /bin/bash` and than install the editor of your choice.

Comment: That's just what needed!

Comment: Still giving "E: Unable to locate package vim"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
docker exec -it -u root api-manager apt -y update && \
docker exec -it -u root api-manager apt-get -y install vim
```